What components do these symbols represent in this schematic
Regarding this IC, What are the two triangular components the SIG IN(pin 14) is coupled to?
First one is a triangle with a circle and a resistor like thing(?) in parallel to it, and it follows a usual triangle(without parallel resistor like thing). Are they inverting and non-inverting buffers with Vdd/2 offset?



Yes, they are inverters and buffers.
An inverter with resistor in parallel with it biases the input and output voltages to be equal so it can be used as a linear amplifier.

Yes, you are right, sorry

Whats the point to invert and whats the point to buffer the inverted signal. Wouldt that introduce 180 degree extra phase shift at the VCO output?

@pnatk It does produce a 180 degree phase shift by itself. Or rather, inverts the signal. But both inputs to the phase comparator are inverted, so they are compared with 0 degree phase shift.

Oh true I just noticed that. Thanks

You are correct, the triangle is a buffer and a triangle with a circle is a negating buffer.
The resistor creates a hysteresis on the input as explained here.

No the resistor does not create a hysteresis, it is not connected like in the answer you provide, which does create hysteresis.

The first "inverter" at pin 14 might see a small signal amplitude that needs amplifying to reach logic levels that other internal logic functions can use.
The feedback resistor around this first inverter forces it to bias near half-Vdd where the "inverter" operates as a linear amplifier with modest gain. If presented with a logic-level input, it operates as a simple inverter.
The following non-inverting "buffer" is likely two-stages of daisy-chained inverters that add even more gain. The object is to amplify any small input signal to logic levels. At buffer output, signal amplitude should be reaching +Vdd at +ve peak, and GND (Vee) at -ve peak.
The input impedance of the amplifier is fairly high, but depends on supply voltage:

with Vdd=3V, input impedance is about \$800k\Omega\$
with Vdd=6V, input impedance is about \$150k\Omega\$

It is anticipated that small input signals should be AC-coupled with an input capacitor. If you are sure that signals at this input are already logic-level within the range of Vdd to Vee, direct connection without capacitor should work.
Larger amplitude inputs should be clipped - going below Vee or above Vdd is forbidden.
Another restriction exists that could apply to pin 14 SIG IN - that is rise/fall time...it should not be too slow:

at Vdd=2V, rise/fall time should be faster than one microsecond.
at Vdd=5V, rise/fall time should be faster than 0.4 microsecond.

